# Folder from one branch, that's been added to my .gitignore, exists when I switch to a different branch

Tags: git, branch

I'm working on two branches: branch A and branch B. The contents of each branch are as follows:

> `**branch A**
>   |-parent
>     |-folder1
>     |-folder2`
>
> `**branch B**
>   |-parent
>     |-folder3
>       |-some_folder
>       |-some_other_stuff
>       |-more_stuff`

I have added "some_folder" to .gitignore. New files are created and added to "some_folder" while working on branch B, hence modifying it. Even though it's supposed to get ignored and git status doesn't list the folder at all (as it should), when I switch to branch A, folder3 is now listed when I execute ls along with "some_folder", but when I execute git status it says my working tree is clean. My working tree in branch A now looks like this:

> `|-parent
>     |-folder1
>     |-folder2
>     |-folder3
>       |-some_folder`

Shouldn't folder3 and "some_folder" be contained in branch B and not carried over when switching to my other branch?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

Git *must* leave `folder3` and subdirectories therein behind if there are any files in them.  In general, it *should* remove them if not, but I've seen corner cases where empty directories get left behind for some reason.  I've never tracked down when: every time I *test* something to see if I found the problem, Git cleans up.

#### Long

Git cares little about folders.  Git cares about *files*.<sup>1</sup>  A file has a path name, such as `dir1/dir2/file.ext`.  The *operating system* cares about folders (directories) and hence, for `file.ext` to exist, Git must *create* `dir1` and then `dir1/dir2`, if they do not exist yet.  Having created those directories, Git can now create `file.ext` within the second one—and that is *all* that Git cares about, on `git checkout`: that files that are *in the commit being checked out* be extracted into both Git's *index*,<sup>2</sup> and the *work-tree*.

The *work-tree* is where you see files: they have their normal everyday form and you can work on them.  The copies in the index are the ones that Git is *really* concerned with, as Git will make any *new* commit that you make, from the copies in the index.  But the copies in the index are in the special, compressed, Git-only form that Git freezes into commits, so Git kindly extracts the files both to the index (where Git wants them) and to your work-tree.  It's the extract-to-work-tree step that creates directories (folders) *if needed*.

When you switch from commit `a123456...` (at the tip of BranchA) to commit `b789abc...` (at the tip of BranchB), Git will:

- remove from the index and work-tree any files that are only in `a123456`
- create in the index and work-tree any files that are only in `b789abc`
- replace in the index and work-tree any files that are different in `b789abc` than they are in `a123456`.

The *remove* and *create* steps sometimes allow Git to remove an empty directory, or require Git to create a new directory.  The *replace* steps generally do not involve directory manipulation.<sup>3</sup>

If you have files that Git is *not* storing in its index, these are *untracked* files.  They exist in the work-tree, but they are not in the index, so they are largely irrelevant to Git.  As long as switching from commit `a123456` (at the tip of BranchA) to `b789abc` (at the tip of BranchB) does not require that Git do anything about these files—i.e., as long as they aren't in `b789abc` either—Git does nothing at all about these files.  Having done nothing about the files, Git does nothing about their containing directories either.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is either a little too weak, or a little too strong.  Git really cares about *commits*.  However, a commit *contains* files: a full and complete snapshot of every file, as of the state it had as of that commit.  More precisely, each commit contains the files it contains—but that's kind of obvious and useless.  Really, it contains *the files that were in the index, when whoever made the commit, made the commit.*  That's why the index (see footnote 2) is so important.

<sup>2</sup>The index is also sometimes called the *staging area*, or the *cache*, depending on who / which part of Git is doing the calling.  The index starts out with a copy of each file from the current commit, ready to go into the *next* commit.  Using `git add` copies new files, or new versions of existing files, into the index, making them ready to commit.  Hence, the best short description of the index is this: **The index is the set of files that will go into the next commit.**  This does not capture all of the little fiddly details—especially, how the index works during merges—but covers the most important part.

<sup>3</sup>There's a rare case where you have, for some reason, wiped out a bunch of work-tree files that *are* in the index from `a123456`, and you've taken away their work-tree directory too.  In this case Git will just re-create the directory so as to satisfy the OS's compulsion to have a directory to hold the file(s).  Git doesn't need, or care about, the directory—Git only needs the file in the index—but *you* probably want the file, so Git makes the directory if necessary, just as it does for files that weren't in `a123456`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that explanation! Makes total sense. I just have one more question: is it possible to store a file in the index, but not have it pushed to the remote or have its changes tracked? I found this elsewhere, but I'm not so sure it's what I want - git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Avel: the index doesn't get sent on `git push`—only *commits* get transferred—but if the file is in the index, it will be in the next commit. You can remove it from the index, commit, and then put it back into the index, for every new commit, but that will be highly inconvenient.

Comment: The `--assume-unchanged` and `--skip-worktree` flags just tell Git: *Whatever's in the index copy of this file, don't bother comparing it to whatever's in the work-tree.* Git will keep using the old copy for each *new* commit, so each new commit will have the same old copy that the old commit had. However, if you jump from one commit to another (as in `git checkout different-branch`), if the file is in both commits and the index copy must therefore be updated, or if it's in the current commit but not in the one you want to check out, Git must replace or remove ... [continued]

Comment: ... replace or remove the index copy, and with it, replace or remove the work-tree copy. So having the file in the index, while *assuming* it's the same as the work-tree copy, is often not a great solution.